# Why calling a script by "scriptName" doesn't work?

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I have a simple script `cmakeclean` to clean cmake temp files:

```
#!/bin/bash -f

rm CMakeCache.txt
rm *.cmake
```

which I call like

```
$ cmakeclean
```

And it does remove CMakeCache.txt, but it doesn't remove `cmake_install.cmake`:

```
rm: *.cmake: No such file or directory
```

When I run it like:

```
$ . cmakeclean
```

it does remove both.

What is the difference and **can I make this script work like an usual linux command (without `.` in front)?**

P.S. 
I am sure the both times is same script is executed. To check this I added `echo meme` in the script and rerun it in both ways.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip

Comment: Haven't got time to write an answer, but the technique is called 'dotsourcing' which makes it googleable for you :-)

Comment: except dotsourcing won't fix the path, and . is not on the PATH by default, for security reasons - to prevent a hacker from placing a script 'ls' in your home folder that does something malicious, for example. The OP might be running two different cmakeclean scripts; `which cmakeclean` or `whence cmakeclean` will tell.

Comment: @Phlip, 
I am sure the both times is same script is executed. To check this I added `echo meme` in the script and rerun it in both ways.

Comment: add `echo *.cmake` before the `rm`, to see if the `*` splat works.

Comment: Where did you put that script? Usually I have to type `./script` to run local scripts without having them to be put in directories in the `PATH`

Comment: How ON EARTH did you come to put that `-f` in the shebang line??  When does this make sense??

Comment: @Alfe It does make sense in certain contexts, when you are writing a very specific script that you want to only ever deal with a controlled set of explicit file names. But then, once you've made that decision, you probably wouldn't then put glob patterns in your script to begin with...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `-f` from your `#!/bin/bash -f` line.

`-f` prevents pathname expansion, which means that `*.cmake` will not match anything. When you run your script as a script, it interprets the shebang line, and in effect runs `/bin/bash -f scriptname`. When you run it as `. scriptname`, the shebang is just seen as a comment line and ignored, so the fact that you do not have `-f` set in your current environment allows it to work as expected.

Comment: Dang. I should have caught that.

Comment: My `echo *.cmake` suggestion would have caught it... C-;

Answer (score 0):

`. script` is short for `source script` which means the *current* shell executes the commands in the script.  If there's an `exit` in there, the *current* shell will exit (and e. g. the terminal window will close).

This is typically used to modify the environment of the current shell (set variables etc.).

`script` asks the shell to fork itself, then `exec` the given script in the child process, and then wait in the father for the termination of the child.  If there's an `exit` in the script, this will be executed by the child shell and thus only terminate this.  The father shell stays intact and unaltered by this call.

This is typically used to start other programs from the current shell.

Comment: and how does that affect whether the script can rm by * ?

Comment: Thanks. But I can't explain by this my observation. Could you do this please? And can I make this script work w\o dot??

Comment: Actually I think that's a _ghost_, meaning a wrong observation.  I base this solely on the fact that I have no idea how the difference in the way of calling could result in this phenomenon.  I rather think that something you haven't told us is responsible for this.

Comment: It's the `-f` on the shebang line, which prevents pathname expansion, and is ignored when sourcing the script as opposed to running it.

Comment: If that's true, @twalberg, then you taught me something :)  How about posting it as an answer?  (And yes, I think you are right.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this about ClearCase? What did you do in your poor life where you've been assigned to work in the deepest bowels of hell?

For years, I was a senior ClearCase Administer. I haven't touched it in over a decade. My life is way better now. The sky is bluer, bird songs are more melodious, and my dread over coming to work every day is now a bit less.

---

Getting back to your issue: It's hard to say exactly what's going on. ClearCase does some wacky things. In a dynamic view, the ClearCase repository on Unix systems is hidden in the shell's environment. Now you see it, now you don't.

When you run a shell script, it starts up a new environment. If a particular shell variable is not *imported*, it is invisible that shell script. When you merely run `cmakeclean` from the command line, you are spawning a new shell -- one that does not contain your ClearCase environment.

When you run a shell script with a *dot* prefix like `. cmakeclean`, you are running that shell script in the current shell which contains your ClearCase environment. Thus, it can see your ClearCase view.

If you're using a snapshot view, it is possible that you have a `$HOME/.bashrc` that's changing directories on you. When a new shell environment runs in BASH (the default shell in MacOS X and Linux), it first runs `$HOME/.bashrc`. If this sets a particular directory, then you end up in that directory and not in the directory where you ran your shell script. I use to see this when I too was involved in ClearCase hell. People setup their `.kshrc` script (it was the days before BASH and most people used Kornshell) to setup their views. Unfortunately, this made running any other shell script almost impossible to do.

Comment: ClearCase is (basically) a file system which provides versioning control on that level.  Each process can have a different _view_ on it, so forking a new shell can make that difference.

Comment: Bad luck.  This was such a great answer (if it had been fitting in this case).

Comment: Sorry. I saw `cmake` and I assume that this was ClearCase since this was one of the ClearCase utilities. The whole shell issue fits ClearCase. Take a look at your `.bash_profile` and see if this could be doing something to your environment -- like setting a directory.